# Testing that a QWidget receives mouse input

Tags: unit-testing, pyqt5

I recently introduced a bug into my PyQt5 app.  I have a QWidget that I render a game in and which I used as the centralWidget in a QMainWindow, I call it the Canvas.  I wanted to render some text over the Canvas so I made the following QWidget that I now use as my centralWidget instead.  It stacks a QLabel over the Canvas.

```
class CentralWidget(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget):
  def __init__(self, content: Canvas) -> None:
    super().__init__()
    self.content = content
    content.setParent(self)

    self.label = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLabel('', self)
    self.label.setObjectName('notification_label')
    self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel { color : white; font-size: 50px }")
    self.label.setAlignment(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

  def resizeEvent(self, event: PyQt5.QtGui.QResizeEvent) -> None: # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    self.label.setGeometry(0, 0, event.size().width(), event.size().height())
    self.content.setGeometry(0, 0, event.size().width(), event.size().height())
```

This rendered just fine but it caused my Canvas to stop receiving mouse input.  I realized my QLabel was intercepting all the input and I solved this by adding `self.label.setAttribute(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)`.  I thought I should add a regression test.

I tried using QTest and QApplication to send mouse events to the QMainWindow expecting them to bubble down but events never seemed to go past the QMainWindow.  Then I tried sending events to my Canvas and I saw that when I do that they bubble up to QMainWindow.  I'm not trying to test that Canvas is properly processing input, I want to test that input events are being routed to the Canvas.  Is there a way to verify this in a unit test?

Comment: Before creating unit tests for generic events, I'd inspect the widget structure. Can you provide an *actual* [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these mouse events bubble up and not down I figured QT must be processing mouse input by finding the lowest QWidget where the mouse input happened and then sending a mouse event to it which suggests a solution involving QWidget::childAt and/or QApplication::widgetAt.  Sure enough, QWidget::childAt ignores widgets with the WA_TransparentForMouseEvents attribute set so I've written a test using QWidget::childAt.

https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp.html#_ZNK14QWidgetPrivate22childAtRecursiveHelperERK6QPointb